# MVP matrix multiplication on WebGPU

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication

### About the order of MVP matrices multiplications for WebGPU/WGSL.

(The issue may be the same for OpenGL/WebGL)

In gl-matrix library
mat4.muptiply is defined by the code in the section "gl-matrix code".

### Questions:

1. I'm confused with the difference between the order of arguments(a, b) and the order of multiplication(Matrix b * Matrix a).
2. The order of multiplication. The following codes work correctly.

```
mat4.multiply(viewProjectionMatrix, projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);
mat4.multiply(mvpMatrix, vpMatrix, modelMatrix);
```

But the above code means `V*P and M*VP`, right?

As of my knowledge, the order of multiplication should be `P*V*M`

#### gl-matrix code

```
export function multiply(out, a, b) {
  let a00 = a[0],
    a01 = a[1],
    a02 = a[2],
    a03 = a[3];
  let a10 = a[4],
    a11 = a[5],
    a12 = a[6],
    a13 = a[7];
  let a20 = a[8],
    a21 = a[9],
    a22 = a[10],
    a23 = a[11];
  let a30 = a[12],
    a31 = a[13],
    a32 = a[14],
    a33 = a[15];
  // Cache only the current line of the second matrix
  let b0 = b[0],
    b1 = b[1],
    b2 = b[2],
    b3 = b[3];
  out[0] = b0 * a00 + b1 * a10 + b2 * a20 + b3 * a30;
  out[1] = b0 * a01 + b1 * a11 + b2 * a21 + b3 * a31;
  out[2] = b0 * a02 + b1 * a12 + b2 * a22 + b3 * a32;
  out[3] = b0 * a03 + b1 * a13 + b2 * a23 + b3 * a33;
  b0 = b[4];
  b1 = b[5];
  b2 = b[6];
  b3 = b[7];
  out[4] = b0 * a00 + b1 * a10 + b2 * a20 + b3 * a30;
  out[5] = b0 * a01 + b1 * a11 + b2 * a21 + b3 * a31;
  out[6] = b0 * a02 + b1 * a12 + b2 * a22 + b3 * a32;
  out[7] = b0 * a03 + b1 * a13 + b2 * a23 + b3 * a33;
  b0 = b[8];
  b1 = b[9];
  b2 = b[10];
  b3 = b[11];
  out[8] = b0 * a00 + b1 * a10 + b2 * a20 + b3 * a30;
  out[9] = b0 * a01 + b1 * a11 + b2 * a21 + b3 * a31;
  out[10] = b0 * a02 + b1 * a12 + b2 * a22 + b3 * a32;
  out[11] = b0 * a03 + b1 * a13 + b2 * a23 + b3 * a33;
  b0 = b[12];
  b1 = b[13];
  b2 = b[14];
  b3 = b[15];
  out[12] = b0 * a00 + b1 * a10 + b2 * a20 + b3 * a30;
  out[13] = b0 * a01 + b1 * a11 + b2 * a21 + b3 * a31;
  out[14] = b0 * a02 + b1 * a12 + b2 * a22 + b3 * a32;
  out[15] = b0 * a03 + b1 * a13 + b2 * a23 + b3 * a33;
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Entirely depends on if you treat your vectors as row or as column vectors and if your matrices are transposed when passing them to GL. It's either `v * MVP` (row) or `PVM * v` (column). I'm also not sure if `mat4.multiply(viewProjectionMatrix, projectionMatrix, viewMatrix)` really means V * P (and not P * V)?